# Is there a way to store the value of DBCC CheckIdent into a variable?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, syntax

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
declare @myCurrentSeedValue int;
select @myCurrentSeedValue = DBCC CheckIdent('MyTable', NORESEED);
```

That obviously is incorrect syntax.  Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can accomplish this?

I know that I can do something like this:

```
select @myCurrentSeedValue = IDENT_SEED('MyTable');
```

But the problem with that is that per MSDN on the IDENT_SEED function:

> Changing the current value of an identity column by using DBCC CHECKIDENT does not change the value returned by this function.

This can be problematic because we have other stored procedures that will call the DBCC CHECKIDENT and reseed the identity column, so I actually need the current seed not the original.

Comment: Select max on the identity column?

Comment: @Blam  With doing that I'm concerned that if a record is deleted prior to me selecting the MAX on the column, that I won't get the true current seed value.

But, now that I reconsider this option, I suppose it would be okay to reseed to that value since the record no longer exists in the database.

I'm leaning towards this being my solution.  Let me try something out and if it works how I'd like it to I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use **Ident_current** you can get the current identity of table, no matter which process update the table identity. It works for any session, any scope.

```
declare @myCurrentSeedValue int;
select @myCurrentSeedValue = IDENT_CURRENT( 'MyTable' )
select @myCurrentSeedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

`IDENT_CURRENT` doesn't return the same value as `DBCC CHECKIDENT` shows if a table haven't been populated at all.

For a just created table `DBCC CHECKIDENT('NewTable', NORESEED)` outputs that current identity is NULL (i.e. has never been assigned):

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current
> column value 'NULL'.

But, `IDENT_CURRENT('NewTable')` returns `1`. Which is correct [according to specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks):

> When the IDENT_CURRENT value is NULL (because the table has never
> contained rows or has been truncated), the IDENT_CURRENT function
> returns the seed value.

The same value `1` `IDENT_CURRENT` returns when there is a single row in a table.

To get correct value of the current identity you can directly fetch this information from `sys.identity_columns` table:

```
SELECT last_value
FROM sys.identity_columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('NewTable')
```

PS: Not sure if this approach will properly work on production DB where table is heavily updated, but for unit tests it suites well. I use this script to figure out what new seed value i should set for table when doing clean up of that table. Because for never populated table the new seed value must be 1 and 0 otherwise.